# How to make a button group work like a radio button group?

Tags: button, twitter-bootstrap-3, radio-group, buttongroup

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and I want to make two buttons work as Radio Buttons, but I can't figure out how. Here goes my code

```
<div class="btn-group" >
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
            PERSONAL
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
            COMPANY
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I select PERSONAL, the other one is deselected (as it should), but the problem is:

- None of them are active when the form is started
- I can deselect both clicking out of the form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1"> Option 1
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2"> Option 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3"> Option 3
  </label>
</div>
```

And initialize with js after:
Enable buttons via JavaScript:

```
$('.btn').button()
```

You can make one of it active adding "active" class to label - "btn btn-primary active" and "checked" to input radio.

Comment: [http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons)

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a better solution nowadays, according to the [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/button-group/#checkbox-and-radio-button-groups):

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio1" autocomplete="off" checked>
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio1">Radio 1</label>

  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio2" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio2">Radio 2</label>

  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio3" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio3">Radio 3</label>
</div>
```